# Does puppeteer support a sandboxed mode on Windows?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer on Windows and want to harden my implementation by using sandbox mode. However, I have to specify `--no-sandbox` for it to work.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md explains two ways of implementing sandbox mode on Linux, but there are no instructions for Windows.

I understand that I can run Linux Docker containers with either WSL 2 or Hyper-V on Windows, but this doesn't satisfy my requirements. I need to run puppeteer and Chrome natively on Windows.

Is sandbox mode supported for puppeteer on Windows?